# Find and mirror data from two worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have been struggling with this program for a while I finally gave up and need help.

- I have a list of 500 plus values on sheet 1 "Layout", in **Table1[Seat Numbers]** column. Some cells contain the same values.
- On sheet 2 "SOFTWARE INFO", there is a master list of those values in **column A**.
- The master list values have other information on the same row, which is what I need on sheet 1.

What I need to do is find matching values on the sheets and copy the row from sheet 2 onto sheet 1 in the corresponding place. I'm at a complete stop with this so any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If the master list is sorted, a call to =VLOOKUP() might work, otherwise try combining INDEX-MATCH, e.g.:

http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/

http://fiveminutelessons.com/learn-microsoft-excel/how-use-index-match-instead-vlookup

which say:

> =INDEX ( Column I want a return value from , ( MATCH ( My Lookup Value , Column I want to Lookup against , Enter “0” ))

So you might have as a formula in Sheet 1:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$10, MATCH(A1, Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10, 1))
```

Where A1 is your Seat Numbers cell, Sheet2!A is the master list column and Sheet2!B is the other information column. You would fill this formula down.